# How do I close a Python 2.5.2 Popen subprocess once I have the data I need?

Tags: python, pipe, popen

I am running the following version of Python:

```
$ /usr/bin/env python --version                                                                                                                                                            
Python 2.5.2
```

I am running the following Python code to write data from a child subprocess to standard output, and reading that into a Python variable called `metadata`:

```
# Extract metadata (snippet from extractMetadata.py)
inFileAsGzip = "%s.gz" % inFile                                                                                                                                                                                                            
if os.path.exists(inFileAsGzip):                                                                                                                                                                                                           
    os.remove(inFileAsGzip)                                                                                                                                                                                                                
os.symlink(inFile, inFileAsGzip)                                                                                                                                                                                                           
extractMetadataCommand = "bgzip -c -d -b 0 -s %s %s" % (metadataRequiredFileSize, inFileAsGzip)                                                                                                                                            
metadataPipes = subprocess.Popen(extractMetadataCommand, stdin=None, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True, close_fds=True)                                                                                                      
metadata = metadataPipes.communicate()[0]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
metadataPipes.stdout.close()                                                                                                                                                                                                             
os.remove(inFileAsGzip) 
print metadata
```

The use case is as follows, to pull the first ten lines of standard output from the aforementioned code snippet:

```
$ extractMetadata.py | head
```

The error will appear if I pipe into head, awk, grep, etc.

The script ends with the following error:

```
close failed: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

I would have thought closing the pipes would be sufficient, but obviously that's not the case.

Comment: This code works fine for me after switching it to use gzip.  If you're just decompressing gzip files, why are you using an obscure tool that nobody knows about ("bgzip")?  Google finds only a years-defunct project on SF.  Use zcat or, better yet, use the gzip module.  You're not likely to get an answer to this if you don't provide a code sample that reproduces the problem.

Comment: I have edited the question to show what the usage case is that triggers the broken pipe. The code I have provided should be sufficient, I think. If I replace "bgzip" with "gzip" I get the same error. The "bgzip" tool is part of a suite called SAMtools, which includes a modified version of "gzip" that performs random access within the archive. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

Hmmm. I've seen some "Broken pipe" strangeness with subprocess + gzip before. I never did figure out exactly why it was happening but by changing my implementation approach, I was able to avoid the problem. It looks like you're just trying to use a backend gzip process to decompress a file (probably because Python's builtin module is horrendously slow... no idea why but it definitely is).

Rather than using `communicate()` you can, instead, treat the process as a fully asynchronous backend and just read it's output as it arrives. When the process dies, the subprocess module will take care of cleaning things up for you. The following snippit should provide the same basic functionality without any broken pipe issues.

```
import subprocess

gz_proc = subprocess.Popen(['gzip', '-c', '-d', 'test.gz'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

l = list()
while True:
    dat = gz_proc.stdout.read(4096)
    if not d:
        break
    l.append(d)

file_data = ''.join(l)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I still get broken pipe errors with this approach. Perhaps Popen() and write() do not cooperate well with respect to piping output to a csh/bash shell.

Comment: Wait, is your shell `csh`? That could be the culprit right there.

Answer (score 1):

I think this exception has nothing to do with the *subprocess* call nor its file descriptors (after calling *communicate* the *popen* object is closed). This seems to be the classic problem of closing `sys.stdout` in a pipe:

http://bugs.python.org/issue1596

Despite being a 3-year old bug it has not been solved. Since `sys.stdout.write(...)` does not seem to help either, you may resort to a lower-level call, try this out:

```
os.write(sys.stdout.fileno(), metadata)
```

Answer (score 0):

There's not enough information to answer this conclusively, but I can make some educated guesses.

First, `os.remove` should definitely not be failing with EPIPE.  It doesn't look like it is, either; the error is `close failed: [Errno 32] Broken pipe`, not `remove failed`.  It looks like `close` is failing, not `remove`.

It's possible for closing a pipe's stdout to give this error.  If data is buffered, Python will flush the data before closing the file.  If the underlying process is gone, doing this will raise IOError/EPIPE.  However, note that this isn't a fatal error: even when this happens, *the file is still closed*.  The following code reproduces this about 50% of the time, and demonstrates that the file is closed after the exception.  (Watch out; I think the behavior of bufsize has changed across versions.)

```
    import os, subprocess
    metadataPipes = subprocess.Popen("echo test", stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True, close_fds=True, bufsize=4096)
    metadataPipes.stdin.write("blah"*1000)
    print metadataPipes.stdin
    try:
        metadataPipes.stdin.close()
    except IOError, e:
        print "stdin after failure: %s" % metadataPipes.stdin
```

This is racy; it only happens part of the time.  That may explain why it looked like removing or adding the `os.remove` call affects the error.

That said, I can't see how this would happen with the code you've provided, since you don't write to stdin.  It's the closest I can get without a usable repro, though, and maybe it'll point you in the right direction.

As a side note, you shouldn't check os.path.exists before deleting a file that may not exist; it'll cause race conditions if another process deletes the file at the same time.  Instead, do this:

```
try:
    os.remove(inFileAsGzip)
except OSError, e:
    if e.errno != errno.ENOENT: raise
```

... which I usually wrap in a function like `rm_f`.

Finally, if you explicitly want to kill a subprocess, there's `metadataPipes.kill`--just closing its pipes won't do that--but that doesn't help explain the error.  Also, again, if you're just reading gzip files you're much better off with the gzip module than a subprocess.  http://docs.python.org/library/gzip.html

Comment: kill() is not available in 2.5.2. There is no stdin; I have edited the question to reflect this. I cannot use the gzip module for this task, although using the gzip binary reproduces the errors.

Comment: The question doesn't make sense now: you're running the script through `head`, but the script has no output.  Please provide a complete, self-contained repro; don't make us experiment with partial code that doesn't even execute as-is, trying to guess what you're talking about.

Comment: I ask for more information and your response is "never mind"?  Seriously?

Answer (score 0):

Getting the first 10 lines from a process output might work better this way:

```
ph = os.popen(cmdline, 'r')
lines = []
for s in ph:
    lines.append(s.rstrip())
    if len(lines) == 10: break
print '\n'.join(lines)
ph.close()
```

Comment: What if I want to handle standard output differently? In other words, instead of using head, I pipe the output into an awk script. I am getting a broken pipe whenever I pipe the output somewhere else.

Comment: If my above version of the script fails when piped through awk, then your problem has nothing to do with the subprocess. What am I missing?